# How to save ArrayList<Float> in Room Database as column

Tags: arraylist, kotlin, typeconverter

I need to write Type Converter to save ArrayList as column. I have tried to write converter, but no result, I get this error:

> "error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type"

```
@Entity(tableName = "WeightRecords")
class WeightRecords : Serializable {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  var id: Long = 0

  @ColumnInfo(name = "weightRecords")
  var weightRecords: Double = 0.0

  @ColumnInfo(name = "days")
  var days: String = ""

  @ColumnInfo(name = "data")
  var data: ArrayList<Float>? = ArrayList()
}

@Dao
abstract class WeightRecordDao : BaseDao<WeightRecords>() {

  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  abstract fun insertWeightRecords(weightRecords: WeightRecords): Long


  @Query("SELECT data FROM WeightRecords")
  abstract fun getData(): ArrayList<Float>

}
```

I need to write Type Converter, please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, answering your question, I think it should be something like

```
@TypeConverter
fun fromArrayListOfFloats(list: ArrayList<Float>?): String {
    return list?.joinToString(separator = ";") { it.toString() } ?: ""
}

@TypeConverter
fun toArrayListOfFloats(string: String?): ArrayList<Float> {
    return ArrayList(string?.split(";")?.mapNotNull { it.toFloatOrNull() } ?: emptyList())
}
```

but maybe storing the list of `floats` isn't the best approach for you? maybe you should create separate table of records, where every `float` will be as a separate row?

Also, I guess, if you have an `ArrayList<Float>` in every row, your `getData` method should return a `List<ArrayList<Float>>`...